# How to use Custom Ubuntu Images with Ubuntu Juju?

Tags: server, juju

I am using Ubuntu Juju in Windows Azure Platform. I want to use customized Ubuntu Image to create the Virtual Machines using JUJU. How to use Customozed Ubuntu Images to create Virtual machines using Ubuntu Juju ?

Answer (score 3):

The Juju way would be to have a collection of charms which customize the vanilla image, rather than having a custom image to start with.

If you want to set all sorts of background things in your image, the best way is to have a [subordinate charm](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/authors-subordinate-services.html) which handles that. This way, you only need the vanilla, trusted, up to date standard image and all your personal changes are kept in one place.